# Changing the color of the point dynamically in highcharts

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I have been able to change the color of point in a graph dynamically, but when I hover over that point then the color of that point is changing to previous color.

I have a fiddle here:  [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J56hm/26/)

```
$(function () {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    }]
});

// the button handler
$('#button').click(function() {

    chart.series[0].data[2].graphic.attr({ fill: '#FF0000' });        
    chart.redraw();
});
```

How can I change the color of the point dynamically in a graph?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are looking to update the marker color dynamically.

you can use update functionality for this

```
chart.series[0].data[0].update();
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yPT73/1/) for your reference. I hope this will be useful for you.

Comment: In my code and in that fiddle, the color doesn't change until you hover over the point (in my case it's a column).  Is there a way to force the color change to be immediate?

Comment: Its a bug in Highcharts that appears to have been just recently fixed: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4622  In the meantime I found a workaround to force the point update using the graphic.attr: jsfiddle.net/jtbuyhdm/1

Answer (score 3):

is this what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-states-select-fillcolor/

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        marker: {
            states: {
                select: {
                    fillColor: 'red',
                    lineWidth: 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not actually. I am looking to change the color of the point without clicking on the point.